# javascript - show number in UI side without exponential

Tags: javascript, html, input, floating-point

I have a data which returns 0.00000000090 from api but in UI side it looks like '9e-10'
I want to show data as 0.00000000090.
My input field is as follows:

```
    <input type="number" 
    ng-model="model.data" 
    name="name" 
    id="id"
    min="0" 
    max="10" 
    required>
```

I can do this with javascript like this:

```
let a = 0.00000000090
a.toFixed(11)
```

Output -> '0.00000000090'

but after toFixed it shows as 0 because value is string now and my input type **must be number.**

Can I solve this with html? or any suggestions other than toFixed()?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine in my example. I've added a step to be 0.000something1 so you could also click the little arrow. Also made an attempt of keeping the display in the decimal format.

```js
number = 0.00000000090

id.value = number.toFixed(11)

id.addEventListener('change', function(ev) {
  this.value = (+this.value).toFixed(11)
})
```

```html
<input type="number" style="width:200px" id="id" min="0" max="10" step="0.00000000001" required>
```